# Representing a long array of numbers with less-long array of letters

Tags: algorithm, hash

There are 10 symbols for number 
And 
There are 24 symbols for letters

So there should be a way to represent a long array of numbers with less-long array of letters

I'm trying to represent userid with the shortest combination of letters 
Do you have an idea about how can that be done

Comment: A library to compress and uncompress arrays of integers very fast. [link](https://github.com/lemire/JavaFastPFOR)

Comment: Giving an example would be better.

Comment: Last I checked, there are 26 letters in the Latin alphabet. 52 if you consider case. There are many different ways to shorten numeric representations. For example, [Base36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36) uses letters and numbers. [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) uses numbers, upper-case, lower-case, and two special characters. There are many others. A simple search will give you implementations in many languages.

Comment: The question is unclear. It seems to me that an array of numbers would have the same length whether or not you converted each number to another base (to shorten the number of characters for that number). Did you mean to shorten one number perhaps?

Comment: *"I'm trying to represent userid with the shortest combination of letters"* why? what's the purpose of this? If the idea is some sort of data-compression, then you're wrong. While a uint32 can store 9 digits in 4 bytes. Your base26 alphabet will use 1-2 bytes per character, that means your string will use 8-16 bits of memory per 4.7xx bits of data in your number

Comment: @Thomas But a 32-bit user id that takes 10 decimal digits to represent will require  only 7 characters in base-26. For example, 1234567890 becomes 3PNFHMA. I don't think the question is about saving memory, but rather about saving typing.

Answer (score 0):

Number's are base 10, as there are 10 numbers.
You have 26 letters. So, you can instead convert the numbers into BASE 26.